# Given $f$ strictly positive. Does $\int _{\Omega}f=0$ implies $\mu (\Omega)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, is Lebesgue integrable function. $A$ is an open, bounded, smooth boundary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume there is a measurable subset of $A$, namely $\Omega$ satisfies

- $f(x)>0 \quad \forall x \in \Omega $
- $\int _{\Omega}f=0$

Can we conclude that $\mu (\Omega)=0$?

Thank you.

Comment: You want $\Omega$ measurable I think. Anyway the result holds, and it doesn't have anything to do with open, smooth, or any of that. Simply look at the subsets $\Omega_k= \{x\in \Omega : f(x) > 1/k\}.$

Comment: Thanks. I edited the measurable condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Following zhw's hint, let $\Omega_k = \{x \in \Omega: f(x) > 1/k\}$.  Note that

- $\int_{\Omega} f \geq \int_{\Omega_k}f \geq \frac 1{k} \mu(\Omega_k)$
- $\Omega = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \Omega_k$